# What is the difference between the LLC and MAC sublayers of the Data Link layer?

Tags: router

The function of the data link layer layer is to format packets into frames, and control transmission of frames between devices on a LAN. Im aware of its two subprotocols which are the Logical Link Control protocol and Media Access Control, but as im trying to do reasearch on the difference between the two, all of the sources that i read are constantly contradicting themselves and mixing up the roles of the two standards, and i have no idea what to make of it.

Can anyone provide me with a concrete explination for which dose what? What is the purpose of both LLC and MAC which differenciates them from the other?

Comment: Please search because there are already questions with answers here, such as the one in the above link.

Comment: Ive already read that serveral times over and haven't gotten anything from it. It escencially just contributes to the sea of conflicting explinations that i mentioned. I want a fresh explination on the topic, and to have somone somewhat experienced in networking who i can ask more intimate questions about the subject, rather than having people parrot already existing sources. Isn't that the point of a forum, discussion? Sorry, im just sick of people telling me to view other sources instead of actually contributing insight to the issue itself.

Comment: "_Isn't that the point of a forum, discussion?_" No, SE sites are _explicitly not_ discussion forums. SE sites are archives of questions and answers. The SE paradigm is that someone has a question that gets answers, and others will probably have the same question, so SE has the archive of the questions and answers. To allow discussions, we have [chat], but it takes a minimal amount of reputation to participate.

Comment: In any case, the answer to the linked question explains it pretty well. Remember that a data-link protocol can carry many different network-layer protocols in its payload, so you need something (LLC) that tells the data-link protocol where to send its payload. They are really not sublayers, simply different functions that the data-link protocol must perform.

Comment: Dosen't really scratch my question or make much sense at all but regardless, thanks. I still disagree with the philosophy that everyone should rely on a single answer to a related question, even when that awnser may have major flaws or points that it dosen't touch on that other users may want insight on, but i digress. Ill look at the link you gave.

Comment: The answer to that question is complete and correct.

Comment: It may very well be, but anyone could say that about any one of the loads of other explinations ive read, which is why i want an intimate explination specific to my question. But, i guess thats the best explination I have right now. Sorry, its just you can never be sure when so many sources are contradicting eachother.

Comment: Incorrect answers here will gather a lot of dissent and other, conflicting answers.

Comment: and if you have questions about the answer, you can always ask them in comments. however in this particular instance I would like to point out that most off the layering aspects is not as precisely defined as you would hope too. You will not get any more precise than the general idea, and each l2 technology will define things in a way that fits this technology the best, and then coarsly map their standards to the layer model. There is neither a clear definition nor a clear separation of layers and sublayers.

Comment: I guess you could argue thats correct, since technically OSI is a more conceptual model rather than practical, but I would at least expect there be some common standard between most systems that follow tcp/ip thats somewhat well documented. Mabey you're right, and if so, well i guess thats that.

Comment: I think i might agree with you @Effie, perhaps different implementations of the model vary enought that you cant really define a fixed way things should be (to an extent). I suppose it is just a general concept.

Comment: different layer 2 technologies, not different imlementations of the model. MAC/LLC are technically not in OSI model, it only has layer 2 :)

Comment: What do you mean by they aren't in OSI? Are you trying to say that the tecknologies that preform they're roles can vary or aren't strictly defined?